# .rdl report not showing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc, rdl

I created a rdl report using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 R2.

I used a simple query

```
Select top 10 id from login_user where client_id =3
```

and the preview show the data as below

[image: report view]

Then i create a c# window application with report viewer and a command button.
on button click I wrote the below code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
 conn.Open();
sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("Select top 10 id from login_user where client_id = "+ 32, conn);
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Report1.rdl";
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("TotalSale", dataset.Tables[0]));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

It executed successfully but the report viewer is not showing the report it is giving a message

> a datasource instance has not been supplied for the datasource

[image: report]

it is because i am using .rdl? only rdlc work with .net? I am stucked here.

Comment: right format Just a moment ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("TotalSale", dataset.Tables[0]));
```

replace "TotalSale" with "DatSet1"

because your data set name in report is DataSet1.

Comment: will do..it will allow me to mark it after 5 min..already upvoted :)